# Windows media player UI

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, skin

I have a question in vb.net
I want to make a short intro then people open my program but I have a little problem. Only way to put this video, is throung windows media player (incorporated in vb.net). Can I remove Windows media play skin (play, stop, contour and other "tools") from form? I need to appear only video in form.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using the `AxWindowsMediaPlayer`, there is a property named `uiMode` which controls the level of UI displayed.  Set it to `"none"` (a string) to remove the UI:

```
myAxWMP.uiMode = "none"
```